# How to get user login info from external provider without registering Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, google-authentication

In .NET Core web application I am trying to log in the user with google as an external provider. Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` I have registered google successfully by adding the following in startup.cs.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

And when user click login I am calling the following to authenticate via google and redirect it to `login/ExternalLoginCallback`

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(
               GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
               new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = $"login/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl={returnUrl}" });
```

In my redirect URL I am trying to get the user info

```
public async Task OnGetExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    var info = await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
}
```

I am using azure cosmos DB database and therefore not using the default identity provider due to which the method `SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` does not work. How can I get the user info without using default Identity from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`?

Comment: You need to implement your own userstore ([extend `UserStoreBase`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L22)) and read/write data to azure cosmos db. I bet there are libraries for cosmosdb integration, so be sure to check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` (or for any other providers) itself adds user information returned from the authentication provider in user claims on successful authentication, it can be accessed from Redirect URL to perform any other tasks such as saving it to database etc.

```
public async Task OnGetExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    // For all claims
    var claims = User.Claims;

    // Individual claim value
    var name = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);    
    var email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
}
```